# Automatic display of TCL sub field in TK label

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a variable and a label that shows the content of the variable. And it changes every time the variable has a new value:

```
global MyVariable
label .mylabel -textvariable MyVariable
```

That works.

Now the problem is that `MyVariable` does not contain the value that I want to show but it is a list of values and I want to execute some code that extracts the sub field that actually contains the data to be displayed. Is there an easy way to put some glue logic into that label in order to do preprocessing on the changed variable content before it gets displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels can only watch whole variables, whether scalar or elements of an (associative) array. They don't have anything for looking inside a list or dictionary or other structure. But you can simulate what you want with a trace.

```
trace add variable x write [list apply {args {
    global x x_1
    set x_1 [lindex $x 1]
}}]
set x [list a b c d e]
label .x1 -textvariable x_1
pack .x1

# Some time later...
lset x 1 fruitbat

# A different type of update
set x "the quick brown fox"
```

You can put in arbitrarily complex calculations into a trace, but it's a really good idea in practice to make them fairly quick so your GUI feels responsive. Reading from a file or database might actually be quick enough though (in some cases) so don't feel too constrained…

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that I understand Donals answer and my problems using it, I want to share my solution

```
    upvar $tmVar tracedVariable
    trace variable tracedVariable w {apply {{nameOfTraceVar v2 op} {
        upvar $nameOfTraceVar localAccess
        .mode.tl_$nameOfTraceVar configure -text [getengvalue $localAccess]
    }}}

    label  ".mode.tl_$tmVar" -text "-"
```

All this is part of a procedure that creates a label for a variable named `tmVar` and is called several times. The lambda now writes directly into the label the derived value.